# How do I use @docRoot in JavaDoc?

Tags: eclipse, javadoc

I am using JavaDoc comments in an Eclipse project. I have an image (png) I make a path to an `<img>` element that is in a folder in the project. The problem is that it is hard-coded: `C:\FilePath\...\image.png`. If another person wants to view this project on their computer it will not show that image because of the hard-coded path.

I stumbled on `@docRoot` but I cannot find anywhere that shows how to use it. Examples would be much appreciated. **I need to make a relative path to the same location in my project so I can display that png on any computer.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an extract from javadoc in the file Button.class of the android-sdk installation.

```
 * . . .   For more information and an example, see <a
 * href="{@docRoot}guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList">State List
 * Drawable . . .
```

Here @docRoot is used to compose a reference to an html tutorial.
In my case @docRoot translates to the following path:

```
file:/C:/Users/<username>/AppData/Local/Android/android-sdk/docs/reference/
```

I ended the path with '/' though in reality there seems to be a problem and the last slash is missing from @docRoot, making all those references bad paths.
If you use it make sure you add the slash after {@docRoot}. I still haven't found if it is possible to change @docRoot.

Comment: Wow that worked great! Thanks for resurrecting a dead question with such little interest. This is such a small thing, but I was shocked at how little documentation there is for this.

Comment: @Jon Well, I was researching myself about \@docRoot and came across your question, it is really no effort to share what I've found so far. Should I find how to set \@docRoot I will post it here too.

Comment: @ilomambo, does this thing works for you in android studio's quick documentation view? AS says that the URL cannot be resolved, but if I generate the jdoc then it works from there. It would be super nice to be able to quickly click on the reference inside android studio.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse JDT 4.4.1 I had to use:

```
    /**
     * @see <a href="../../../../../../../target/process-test-coverage/report.html">Process Test Coverage Report</a> 
     */
    public void calculateCoverageForAllTests() throws Exception {
        ...
    }
```

because `{@docRoot}` did not seem to work in the Javadoc view and hovers:

```
    /**
     * @see <a href="{@docRoot}/target/process-test-coverage/report.html">Process Test Coverage Report</a> 
     */
```

and produced the following error :

> **Unable to load page**
>
> Problem occurred while loading the URL
>   file:///home-falko/camunda/eclipse-workspace/compensation-triggered-from-outside/src/test/java/com/camunda/demo/compensation_triggered_from_outside/{@docRoot}/target/process-test-coverage/report.html

although this should be working according to the [Eclipse JDT 3.5 Release Notes](http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.5-200906111540/eclipse-news-part2.html)